# Babel support for static class properties

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to make a single js bundle file using babel & webpack, and I'm constantly getting these parse errors, as if appropriate babel transforms are not working at all. I'm using 'react-native' preset for babel, which includes following plugins:

```
  'babel-plugin-react-transform'
  'babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions'
  'babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties'
  'babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas'
  'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-constants'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals'
  'babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'
  'babel-plugin-transform-object-assign'
  'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread'
  'babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name'
  'babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx'
  'babel-plugin-transform-regenerator'
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of'
```

So this plugin 'babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties' should do the transform I'm looking for but for some reason it's not working. Even when I add this plugin manually to .babelrc file I get the same output. This is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./~/@exponent/react-native-navigator/ExNavigator.js
Module parse failed: /Users/Arbor/Desktop/ArborMobileApp/backend/node_modules/@exponent/react-native-navigator/ExNavigator.js Unexpected token (24:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export default class ExNavigator extends React.Component {
|   static Styles = ExNavigatorStyles;
|   static SceneConfigs = ExSceneConfigs;
|   static Icons = ExNavigatorIcons;
 @ ./logic/initialize.js 14:175-218
```

Here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": ["react-native"],
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './entryPoint.js',
  output: {
      path: './release',
      filename: 'basecomponents.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  }
};
```

And package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-native-base-components",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "entryPoint",
  "dependencies": {
    "@exponent/react-native-navigator": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-orientation": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.3",
    "webpack": "^2.0.7-beta"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -f dist/basecomponents.js && clear && node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: There is an entry in package json for babel preset 'react-native', I accidentally deleted it while posting this question, here it is: "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.5.6"

Comment: I figured out what was the issue, I had "exclude: /node_modules/" line in the webpack config, this is why babel was not transforming that part of the code.